# Null items coming in library items results

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get items in specific library using

```
Get-SPWeb http://sitecollection/sites/site/subsite |
    Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
    Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" -and
            $_.Name -like "SitePages" } |
    Select -ExpandProperty Items |
    Select Name, {$_.File.Length}, url
```

However, I am getting null, but there are items in the library. 
I have tried -eq also, but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SPList` does not have `Name` property. Instead use `Title` property. Modified code:

```
Get-SPWeb http://sitecollection/sites/site/subsite |
    Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
    Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" -and
            $_.Title -eq "Site Pages" } |
    Select -ExpandProperty Items |
    Select Name, {$_.File.Length}, url
```